# Keyboard hide in iPad don't work

Tags: ipad, keyboard, uitextfield

I have many views and the problem appears in all of them.
I have 'n' UITextField's in a UIView, I implement the UITextFieldDelegate method to hide the keyboard when the user press the "Done" button like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Nothing special.
The problem is that doesn't work. The method executes without problem but the keyboard doesn't hide.

Any help?

Comment: After searching through posts that only talking about hooking up the delegate correctly (which I was doing), I came across this post: [iPad 'dismiss keyboard' button doesn't dismiss keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888735/ipad-dismiss-keyboard-button-doesnt-dismiss-keyboard) Posting for those who are having my same issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the view where the field was display was deployed as UIModalPresentationFormSheet, change it to UIModalPresentationPageSheet fix the problem.