# iPad 'dismiss keyboard' button doesn't dismiss keyboard 

Tags: ios, uikeyboard, dismiss

I have a UITextField in a Landscape view, and when I press the 'dismiss keyboard' button in the lower right of the UIKeyboard view, the keyboard does NOT disappear. Is there a way to programmatically listen for when this key was pressed? Or is there a connection I am not seeing that will make this keyboard go away?
This is iOS 4 and XCode 4. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem today and I wondered, wy it works in Apple's KeyboardAccessory Sample Code.
So I did reverse engineering. The ViewController was not the mistake I made in my case.

In the implementation of UIApplicationDelegate there is the entry point of application, where root viewcontroller and window will be setup `- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application`. If you forgot to add root viewcontrollers view to window as subview, the dismiss-keyboard-button wouldn't work in any view of your app.

```
@class ViewController;

@interface KeyboardAccessoryAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
  UIWindow *window;
  ViewController *viewController;
}

  @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ViewController *viewController;

@end
```

...

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

  [window addSubview:viewController.view];
  [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Please don't forget to setup the outlets in the main xib file.

I dont know why this is related to keyboards behavior. But my theory is, that the responder chain is not linked to window, but it needs.

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell the text field that is accepting the keyboard input to no longer be the first responder.

```
[UITextField resignFirstRepsonder];
```

Comment: Yes - that isn't a problem. The keyboard disappears when that message is sent. The problem is that nothing happens when the 'dismiss keyboard' button in the lower right of the iPad keyboard (which looks like a little keyboard icon) is pressed. And the text field doesn't receive any input from that key. I'm really wondering if I have come across a bug at this point. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

To dismiss the keyboard using the dismiss keyboard button you need to implement the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //Check if your text field is first responder, and if it is, have it resign
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to dismiss the keyboard by tapping outside of it, use

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UIView* view in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            [view resignFirstResponder];
        }

        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
            [view resignFirstResponder];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @capt kettch - I did have this in my code already... here is a snippet... I have the class set up as the delegate for the UITextField: `@interface SettingsController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> { ... ` then in the method you mention I check with: `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if([textField isFirstResponder])
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }` so - I think things are connected correctly - anything seem missing? Thanks again!

Comment: I forgot to mention, you should make sure that your textfield has its delegate set to the viewcontroller (most likely self)