# Dismiss keyboard button doesn't work 0 iOS

Tags: ipad, uitextfield

For some reason, in my app, the dismiss keybaord button on the lower right hand corner never works. I am able to use resignFirstResponder on the UITextField correctly, but if the user tries to us that button, nothing happens. any ideas?

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"shouldend");
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"should begin");
    return YES;
}
```

Additional Info: This is a problem for the entire app. The button never works in any textField in my app.

Comment: After searching through posts that only talking about hooking up the delegate correctly (which I was doing), I came across this post: [iPad 'dismiss keyboard' button doesn't dismiss keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888735/ipad-dismiss-keyboard-button-doesnt-dismiss-keyboard) Posting for those who are having my same issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` method `– textFieldShouldEndEditing:`:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    return YES;
}
```

To test what's going on, you can also put in simple `NSLog`s in `– textFieldDidBeginEditing:` and `– textFieldDidEndEditing:`. This will tell you whether to gesture is being received or not.

Comment: shouldBegin is getting called properly, but shouldEnd is never called, nor is didEnd. ShouldReturn is also called properly when the enter button is pressed.

Comment: Make sure that the connections are properly set. If using IB, make sure to drag a connection from the `UITextField` to the first responder. If setting this up programmatically, be sure to set the delegate.

Comment: what do you mean drag a connection to the first responder? The delegate is set, but I have never messed with connecting to first responders before. Which first responder should it connect to?

Comment: @Brodie: If the delegate is set, then both `didEnd` and `shouldEnd` should be called.

Comment: Quite true - but the delegate is set in IB and I even just set the delegate in code to make sure. They still arent being called for some reason. Strange since the other methods are being called. Updated question with my code.