# UITextViews hide keyboard button won't work

Tags: objective-c, ios

All UITextViews on my application just won't hide the keyboard when i click the "Hide Keyboard" button on the input keyboard.

This is very strange since UITextFields behave normally and theres absolutely no delegation class linked to the TextViews, so there is absolutely no reason for this behavior.

Anyone who faced this problem and solved it?

Comment: After searching through posts that only talking about hooking up the delegate correctly (which I was doing), I came across this post: [iPad 'dismiss keyboard' button doesn't dismiss keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888735/ipad-dismiss-keyboard-button-doesnt-dismiss-keyboard) Posting for those who are having my same issue...

Comment: thanks, but i'm already doing what's explained in the correct answer to that question. plus, it's only happening with UITextViews, the UITextFields are behaving normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the return key to something like "Done" and then use the delegate method and see if a line break occurred:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if ( [text isEqualToString: @"\n"] ) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I did that, the Done button hides the keyboard and there's no line break. The "Hide keyboard" button still doesn't work. The only problem with this solution is that i want to allow line breaks.